# Restricting direct access to files using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security, file-access, restrictions

I have video files in a folder. And I want to restrict the users from directly accessing them. I have my .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(mp4|flv)$ - [F]
```

IDEA:

**This will allow the browser to access my video when requested from page. But it will deny direct access from url.**

Actual response:

Its working fine for Chrome. But in all other browsers (firefox, opera, midori) Its giving StreamNotFound error. What is the issue? Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(mp4|flv)$ - [NC,F]
```

Comment: Why would that fix the problem OP is having?

Comment: Can't say with 100% surety but various browser extensions can customize OR strip out `%{HTTP_REFERER}`

Comment: Check from server what `HTTP_REFERER` is actually being received from Firefox, opera etc.